# How to present timestamp date retrieved from firestore in a nice format

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I retrieved the date from firestore saved in the timestamp format like this:

```
        Date retrievedDate = class.getDate();
```

the date saved in firestore format:
//it is in timestamp format

[image]

How to convert this date to a normal presentable format like : 7 June 2020, Sunday, 15:09 PM?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look into Android's date formatting capabilities. The user's most desirable format is going to depend on a bunch of things, including locale and timezone. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat

Comment: is your timestamp saved in firestore that is in milliseconds?

Comment: @NobanHasan No, it is saved in timestamp like the screenshot above

Comment: You can check out the link. This may help you to format your ZonedDatetime. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/parse-string-to-date-time-utc-gmt/